# CSS body width does not fill 100 percent

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a webpage and I noticed this issue.

[image: body full width issue print screen]
Please, post anything you get in mind it will be very helpful!

Check the website [here](http://dev.mariachi.com.br/europel/)

EDIT: Added the website link

Comment: add clear:both; where you have use the float:property

Answer (score 29):

Might want to check if this might work, it did for my particular issue.

```
body {
    min-width: fit-content;
}
```

Added the answer of John Mcnulty as an paste because weblinks might go as 404.
And this actually helped a bit to normalize the css without having browsers put their own css in it.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the body wasn't respecting the width and had to force a min-width: fit-content but it worked...

Answer (score 11):

you need to use [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/):

use this code:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

all element have some style in default you need to reset them.

Comment: I don't know why this will be the problem since I'm using normalize to reset all my css.

Comment: @Cald i need to see you html and css, can you create a online demo ?

Answer (score 4):

Though this is a very old issue, I have personally run into this thread twice without being able to resolve this issue (I keep forgetting what I did to fix it). For future viewers (me included) where setting padding and margin to 0 didn't magically fix your problem try "position: fixed" in the body.

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
body
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Just as a tip, you should not specify a unit when setting a property to 0.  It is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Ähm, your div.container has a width of 970px. And this breaks your body width because your layout isn't fluid. Use media queries or procentual widths will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some [`clear:both;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) that are missing..

Up : It's probably not that, but maybe other sub-elements block width and does not allow the page to take its total width. If you have any float should think about making a clear before the footer (as I see a div on the right).

See your html / css code would be better :)

Comment: Please expand on where and why `clear:both;` may be missing, and give a link to relevant articles/documentation.

Comment: that was really a perfect answer, That happenes due to clear both

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this worked for me:

```
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

My padding on sections of 100% was adding the padding to the page width resulting in width 100% + (padding value * 2)

Answer (score 0):

set the max-width of your image using the percent, rather than pixel, rem, em, etc.

```
.resizable-img {
    max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was nothing to do with the CSS at all. It seem'd that chromium had bugged out and thought the dev tools was still open at a certain width.

Only closing the tab and re-opening it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you included a CSS reset in your page?

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Yes I did. I'm using normalize!

Comment: @Cald good practice but Normalize.css does not put the width of `<html>` and `<body>` to 100%.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I know that but I did it myself in my less file! body, html {min-width: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 1em;}

Answer (score -2):

if you don't need responsive or fluid design(mentioned in other answers), final solution is to set minimum width for body.

set min-width on body to the most wide element width(in most cases - .container) and remove width and min-width form html element.

```
body {
    width:100%;        
    min-width:980px;
}
```

you must expect that you will lose customers when your design is non-responsive

Answer (score -5):

The issue persist only if you resized the Browser window. As its not breaking the website, You could leave that issue.

or

If you are creating a non-responsive site, You can do this simply by adding specific width to html and body. something like this

```
html, body {
  width:1170px;
}
```