# Html body is not getting full width in tailwindcss

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am new in tailwindcss. But I am having an issue here.

Look at the screenshots, the background color is not applying in the navbar. Also the whole html body is not getting full width in medium and small screens.

What I don't understand is that I still haven't used any of the responsive classes from tailwindcss like md, sm or lg. But there are serious problems with width and I tried using tailwind class of w-full and w-screen. None of them work.
Here's the screenshot of the problem
[image: screenshot-2]
[image: screenshot-3]
[image: screenshot-4]
[image: screenshot-1]

You can find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-curran-jdyup

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

ok, look at this GIF, guys.

[image: for_github2]

I am trying to recreate the problem in Tailwind Play. But I couldn't. Then I noticed that the same line of code works perfectly in Tailwind Play but not with nextjs. I don't know what the problem here is but I shared both the Tailwind Play and NextJS code below.
Tailwind Play:

```
<div class="flex justify-between items-center p-5 bg-indigo-800 text-white">
      <div class="ml-16">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <div class="">
            <h4 class="tracking-widest uppercase">GrayScale</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="lg:hidden">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="text-gray-400 mt-1 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:outline-none"
            >
              <svg
                class="w-6 h-6"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mr-16">
          <a
            key={link.label}
            class="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md"
          >
            Home
          </a>
          <a
            key={link.label}
            class="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md"
          >
            Home
          </a>
          <a
            key={link.label}
            class="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md"
          >
            Home
          </a>
          <a
            key={link.label}
            class="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md"
          >
            Home
          </a>
          <a
            key={link.label}
            class="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md"
          >
            Home
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

NextJS Code:

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center p-5 bg-indigo-800 text-white">
      <div className="ml-16">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <div className="">
            <h4 className="tracking-widest uppercase">GrayScale</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="lg:hidden">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="text-gray-400 mt-1 hover:text-white focus:text-white focus:outline-none"
            >
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mr-16">
        <a className="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md">
          Home
        </a>
        <a className="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md">
          Home
        </a>
        <a className="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md">
          Home
        </a>
        <a className="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md">
          Home
        </a>
        <a className="p-2 pr-2 uppercase tracking-widest font-semibold hover:bg-indigo-900 hover:text-gray-400 rounded-md">
          Home
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you have found out the solution, can you please share it?

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with the chrome developer tool.  At first, this worked.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

However, the problem returned.

**SOLUTION:**
It turned out the page had too much content, and chrome was not waiting to set the viewport size until all the content had loaded.  Once I removed a large table of data.  All started working as needed.

I will load the content in ajax and add pagination.

Another thing worked by class="hidden" on my long table of data and the after load.  Remove the "hidden" class.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding max-w-full to the container that you want full width.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "w-screen" class instead container and it solved :)

`<div className='w-screen'>Header</div>`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

You should consider new responsive scenarios for these columns overflowing containers.
Or you should give the container `overflow: hidden`. The problem is with them.

Comment: I tried giving them containers....but it didn't work. Also what do you mean by new responsive scenarios?

Comment: So why the problem still exists when I commented out those sections?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54898746/1762002).

Basically, a 'meta' viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling. So you need to add:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
What did the trick for me was 'max-w-max' put that to your container (not the body tag), whick makes the max width equal to the max width of the content (so no more white on the right).

Answer (score 0):

I face exactly this same issue. Looks like [it's not tailwindcss specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20400755/9157799). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57860826/9157799) solves it for me:

Place [`min-w-fit`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width) to the top element or the direct child of the body.

```html
<div class="min-w-fit lg:min-w-0 lg:max-w-5xl lg:mx-auto">
  <p>something</p>
</div>
```

Just note that [min-width always override max-width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16063771/9157799) so when you need max-width e.g. in larger screen, you might need to readjust the min-width.

### Update

Turns out the root of the problem is **overflowing flex items**, which in my case, is caused by long words e.g. URL. Note: Normally the default `min-width` of an HTML element is `0` but for flex items it's `auto`. The thing is,  when the `min-width` is reached (which in my case is decided by the longest word), as they overflow as the screen gets smaller, the `min-width:auto` keep the element from shrinking and instead shrinks everything else. It shrinks the fixed font size to keep the element width and because it also shrinks the parent element, it's true that the element is actually overflowing (check with inspect element).

**Solution:**

Add `min-width: 0` to the outmost container that's overflowing its parent. If the overflow is caused by long words, don't forget to handle the text overflow with [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) or [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap).

**Source:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66689926/9157799
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784508/9157799